# Objective C - link items in sorted array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I have a sorted array of objects, sorted by a NSNumber attribute on each object 'rate'

I wish to link each object to the next object in the sorted array with a different rate value.

(ie.  I will get a list of objects like this:

object1_link = first_object_with_2nd_highest_value

object2_link = first_object_with_3rd_highest_value

object3_link = first_object_with_4th_highest_value

.....

object(N)_link = first_object_with_(N+1)_highest_value

)

Do any mathematicians or computer scientists know a way of doing this in O(N) time? (ie. without using nested loops)?

Otherwise O(N^2).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't your array already sorted? Why not just loop over it once and set the link to the next object?

Comment: Yes - The problem is that there are duplicate entries for the same value. So if I do that, I'm just going to end up linking objects with the same value

Ie. I'll get
object1_link = second_object_with_1st_highest_value

object2_link = third_object_with_1st_highest_value

Comment: If you have duplicate entries then shouldn't you have both link 1 & 2 point to it? Any how. It should be easy to test if the object you are about to link to is the same as the previous link and if so, just skip it and move to the next value until it's not a duplicate...

Comment: I suppose you meant `Otherwise O(2*n)` instead of `O(n^2)`... :D or maybe I misunderstood you basic problem but it is hard to image why the time would be `O(n^2)` in that case.